# Load template based on domain

Tags: django, django-templates

There are two sites with different domains (`first_example.com`, `second_example.com`). They have a common database and common logic.
The task is what needs to be done so that for each of the sites its own template is loaded.

For example, there will be a file structure

```
__landing
____templates
______landing
________site_1
__________ index.html
________site_2
__________ index.html
```

It is necessary that when opening the `first domain`, templates from `site_1` are loaded.
And when opening the `second domain`, templates from `site_2` were loaded.

I think I need to write somehow `template_loader`, but I don’t understand yet how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nesting the "per-site" templates within the template directory structure, use two distincts root template directories, ie instead of

```
/templates
   /app-one
      site1/
        index.html
      site2/
        index.html
```

you want:

```
/site1-templates
   /app-one
      index.html
/site2-templates
   /app-one
      index.html
```

Then in each setting file (you have a distinct settings for each site do you ?), just specify the proper path for `TEMPLATES.DIRS`

```
# site1 settings

TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'site1-templates'),
    ],
    'OPTIONS': {
    # etc
    }
 }]
```

NB: if you need to keep some common templates, you can have them in a third directory (ie `basetemplates`) and add this *after* the site-specific path in `TEMPLATES.DIRS`.

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'site1-templates'),
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'base-templates'),
    ],
    'OPTIONS': {
    # etc
    }
 }]
```

Comment: Thnx. If I write in the view `render (request, "/ app-one / index.html" {})` and if I go from the `first_example.com` domain , the template `site1-templates/app-one/index.html` will be loaded, and if I come from the `second_example.com` domain, the `site2-templates/app-one/index.html` will be loaded